# How to normalize nested JSON with strings consisting dictionary?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

I want to normalize and create dataframe from nested JSON with strings that consists another dict.
I already tried

```
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/conversation_data.json', 'r') as f:
  data = json.load(f)

table = pd.json_normalize(data, 'conversations')
table
```

but it returns all the individual strings separated in rows. How can I return a dataframe table with conversation_id, author_id, and so on?

this is the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "data_loaded": "2019-12-21 12:00:22.189441 UTC",
    "ticket_id": "222815",
    "ticket_created_at": "2019-12-21T12:07:52Z",
    "conversations": "{\"conversations\":[{\"conversation_id\":\"866229422292\",\"author_id\":\"391349919632\",\"body\":\"==========Write below this ...\",\"created_at\":\"2019-12-21T12:07:52Z\",\"via_channel\":\"email\"}]}"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The string appears to be itself a JSON fragment. It doesn't actually contain those backslashes (those are part of how the string is represented for printing), so all you need to do is feed it back to the JSON parser.

`json.load` and `json.dump` are used with files; the corresponding functions to operate on strings are `json.loads` and `json.dumps` (with an "s" for "s"tring).

So for example:

```
# pull out the embedded JSON string from the parsed JSON, then re-parse it
conversations = json.loads(data[0]["conversations"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
data = [
  {
    "data_loaded": "2019-12-21 12:00:22.189441 UTC",
    "ticket_id": "222815",
    "ticket_created_at": "2019-12-21T12:07:52Z",
    "conversations": "{\"conversations\":[{\"conversation_id\":\"866229422292\",\"author_id\":\"391349919632\",\"body\":\"==========Write below this ...\",\"created_at\":\"2019-12-21T12:07:52Z\",\"via_channel\":\"email\"}]}"
  }
]

conversations = json.loads(data[0]['conversations'])

table = pd.json_normalize(conversations, 'conversations')
print(table)
```